# Android New Project Creation

Tags: android-studio

Whenever I am creating a new project it's showing run task error.

> C:\Users\C0de-01\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\src\main\res\values\colors.xml:4:39: Error: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.

If I correct this another xml file showing the another error without closing entity. How to resolve this error. Why its not creating default xml colour file. But I tried to uninstall the android studio and install it again. Still I have the same problem.

Comment: What is the error typically? (I mean the code.)

Comment: Check your Android Studio new project template file for any possible errors, located in `<Android Studio Installation Path>/plugins/android/lib/templates`.

Comment: When you uninstalled the android studio, did you delete the projects folder before reinstalling ¿¿